# Define a conditional probability using measure theory

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-probability

I am not a math major, just trying to formulate my research question in a more rigorous way.

Suppose I have a probability measure $\pi_{\theta}$ and another variable $\phi=g(\theta)$. How do i formulate the conditional probability measure $\pi_{\theta\mid \phi}(A)$ for a measurable $A$?

I was trying $\pi_{\theta\mid \phi}(A)=\frac{\int_{A} \mathbf{1}\{g(\theta) =\phi\}d\pi_{\theta} (\theta)}{\int_{\Theta} \mathbf{1}\{g(\theta) =\phi\}d\pi_{\theta} (\theta)}$. (For now let's just say density of $\phi$ is non-zero on $g(\Theta)$, I would love to hear any insights about regularity condition as well.)

However, when I plug in an uniform distribution as an example, that does not seem to work. Say $\theta\sim U(-1,1)$ and $\phi=\theta^2$, then $\int_{\Theta} \mathbf{1}\{g(\theta) =\phi\}d\pi_{\theta} (\theta)$ becomes zero and that's not what i want.
I was hoping to find a non-trivial conditional distribution for this scenario.

If anyone could tell me what part went wrong that will be great!

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think you've hit a problem?  The conditional distribution of $\theta$ when given $\theta^2$ will be degenerate.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question. I guess what I really want to see is something like $\pi_{\theta\mid \phi=\frac{1}{4}} ([0,1])=\frac{1}{2}$ here, i.e. It is equally likely for $\theta$ to be $0.5$ or $-0.5$

Comment: Ah.  Of course, you are measuring over an interval.  You should be using a dirac delta function rather than an indication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the **dirac delta** rather than an indicator.  $$\pi_{\theta\mid g(\theta)}(A\mid\phi)=\mathbf 1_{\phi\in g(\Theta)}\int_A \delta_{g(\theta)-\phi}\,\mathrm d \pi_\theta(\theta)$$

For $\theta\sim\mathcal U(-1..1)$ and $g(t)=t^2$ $$\pi_{\theta\mid\theta^2}([0..1]\mid \phi)=\mathbf 1_{\phi\in[0..1^2]}\int_{0}^1\delta_{x^2-\phi}\cdot\tfrac 12\mathrm d x \\~= \frac 12\,\mathbf 1_{\phi\in[0..1^2]}$$

Comment: Right...! I always mixed them up even back in grad school. Thank you, Graham!

Comment: Hi Graham, can i ask a follow-up question? In a more general setting (forget about the uniform and quadratic functional form), how to prove $\pi_{\theta\mid g(\theta)}(g^{-1}(\phi)\mid\phi)=1$ in the definition you gave above, when $g(\theta)=\phi$ is a continuum?